# java framework for transactions based website

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, struts

I am new to java and came to know about the java frameworks

I want to know if i have to make a recharge based website which framework is best suitable for this and why?

and which database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for me great frameworks are:

1) Back-End: Spring + JPA/Hibernate

2) Front-End: Struts2 + Freemarker

It is simple to develop and has great documentation. Is not hard to implement complicated task. 
Also for Front-End is great JSF (Primefaces), but **ONLY** for simple tabs, simple datatable, when it became to complicated objects, Primefaces has many newns and I switch to Struts2.

Here is developers rates, you can make your own opinion:

[here](http://devrates.com/project/search?query=%5Bjava%5D)

Enjoy :)

Comment: Is is possible to make front-end in one frame work and back end in another?

Comment: Yes, of couse. You may use Spring (it has own container for back-end) and JSF(Primefaces, Richfaces) for front-end or Struts2 (**NOT** Struts1 :) ).